# Strongloop: Add related model instance to a database

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have three models with relation as :

common/models/customer.json

```
"relation": {
"fundSource": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "CreditCard",
  "foreignKey": "",
  "through": "fundingEntities"
   }
}
```

common/model/funding-entities.json

```
"relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "CustomerId"
    },
    "creditCards": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "CreditCard",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
}
```

common/model/credit-card.json

```
 "relations": {
   "customer": {
    "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
    "model": "BoomCustomer"
    }
}
```

where customer can load fund to their accounts via fundSource ( credit cards, paypal, etc)

I have tried to add fundSource to customer if one doesnot exist as :

```
customer.fundSource.create(data, function(err,res){
   console.log(err);
 }
```

But console says undefined is not a function.

How can I achieve this? I am using mongoDB datasource.

Comment: A hasMany relationship may pluralize your name to be `fundSources`, did you `console.dir(customer)` ?